# Enter the date when the checkbox is selected

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to make it so that when the checkbox is selected it puts today's date in the database, I tried using timestamp but it puts it in all the spaces in the column, I'm a beginner in php
The code I made was this:

```
<?php
            if (isset($_POST['Abate'])){
              $Abate="Sim";
              $data=time();
              $DiaAbate= date("Y/m/d", $data);
          }
          else{
              $Abate="Nao";
              $DiaAbate="";
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: Share the screenshot for the inserted record. This will help to fix the issue.

Comment: _"but it puts it in all the spaces in the column"_ - what do you mean by that?

Comment: The code you have shown just prepares some data, it does not show us where you actually INSERT or UPDATE the record(s).

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time using stackoverflow I didn't know how the comments worked, the part of the code where you insert the data in the database is like this:
(I had to shorten the code due to the character limit)

Comment: $Abate = $_POST['Abate'];
              $DiaAbate = $_POST['DiaAbate'];

              $query = "INSERT INTO pc (Abate,DiaAbate) VALUES ('$Abate','$DiaAbate')";
              $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
          
              if($query_run)
              { 
                  $_SESSION['status'] = "Inserted Succesfully";
                  header("Location: indexx.php");
              }
              else
              {
                  $_SESSION['status'] = "Not Inserted";
                  header("Location: indexx.php");
              }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not included your table structure (CREATE TABLE statement) so I have assumed you have a DATE column for storing $DiaAbate. I have also assumed that the submitted date is in 22/11/2022 format. If you are using a different format for the POSTed date value, you will need to change the format string passed into [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Your current code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) as you are combining your static strings with user input without any validation. The simple example below uses a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for the insert query -

```
if (isset($_POST['Abate'])){
    $Abate = 'Sim';
    // create a date from the posted date string adn format it
    // see https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php
    $DiaAbate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_POST['DiaAbate'])->format('Y-m-d');
} else {
    $Abate = 'Nao';
    $DiaAbate = null;
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO pc (Abate, DiaAbate) VALUES (?, ?)';
$query_run = mysqli_execute_query($con, $query, [$Abate, $DiaAbate]);

if ($query_run) {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'Inserted Succesfully';
    header('Location: indexx.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['status'] = 'Not Inserted';
    header('Location: indexx.php');
}
```